# Flutter: Google ML Kit alternative for desktop?

Tags: flutter, face-detection, google-mlkit, flutter-desktop

I have an idea for a desktop app that needs to detect whether a user has his/her eyes closed and track the orientation of the user's head in real time.

Google ML Kit offers these two features right out of the box and with the [google_ml_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit) Flutter package it's as easy as pie to get it up and running in an Android or iOS app.

But sadly the Google ML KIT doesn't support MacOS or Windows.

Is there an alternative package for desktop that doesn't require me to train the models myself and would be easy to integrate into a Flutter app?

Comment: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/ provides some detection APIs cross-platform. However, it is probably not as easy as ML Kit to use. You could take a look.